# Bounding the size of lower ramification breaks

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a totally ramified degree $p^n$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Write $G_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}$ for the set of $\mathbb{Q}_p$-algebra homomorphisms from $K$ into some fixed algebraic closure, so that in the Galois case, $G_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p} = \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)$. In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00013-009-0026-3.pdf), Lbekkouri defines the **lower ramification number** $v_\sigma$ of $\sigma \in G_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}$ to be
$$
v_\sigma = v\Big(\frac{\sigma(\pi) - \pi}{\pi}\Big),
$$
where $\pi$ is a uniformiser of $K$. The $v_\sigma$ are precisely the integers $i$ such that $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is nontrivial, where the $G_i$ are the ramification subgroups of $G_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}$. These quotients are subgroups of $U_i/U_{i+1} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where $U_i = 1 + (\pi^i)$, so exactly $n$ of them are nontrivial, hence the $v_\sigma$ take $n$ distinct values as $\sigma$ ranges over $G_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}$. Let us order these values as $v_0 < v_1 < \ldots < v_{n-1}$.

**Question:** Lbekkouri claims that we have $v_r \leq \frac{p^{r+1}}{p-1}$ for each $r$. Why is this true?

**My attempt:** I have tried to solve the problem for $r=0$ and $p$ odd. That is, I want to show that $v_0 \leq \frac{p}{p-1}$. Since I am assuming $p$ odd, I need $v_0 \leq 1$. In other words, we want some $\sigma$ such that $v(\sigma(\pi) - \pi) \leq 2$, which is equivalent to
$$
\sigma(\pi) \not \equiv \pi \pmod{\pi^3}
$$
for some $\sigma$. So basically, the roots of the minimal polynomial $f(X)$ of $\pi$ can't be too close together. Somehow, I want to extract a contradiction from the assumption that $\sigma(\pi) \equiv \pi \pmod{\pi^3}$ for all $\sigma$. Assuming that this is the case, we can write
$$
f(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{p^n}(X - \pi - \pi^3\theta_i)
$$
for integers $\theta_i$ of the algebraic closure of $K$. I have considered the coefficients of $X^{p^n-1}$ and $X^0$ in this polynomial to try and find a contradiction (since we know these must be in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and that $f(X)$ is Eisenstein), but I haven't been successful. I also though about trying to apply Hensel's Lemma to
$$
f(X) \equiv (X - \pi)^{p^n} \pmod{\pi^3},
$$
but again I haven't managed to find a contradiction. My feeling is that somehow, we might be able to leverage the proximity of the roots to "lift the degeneracy" from $f \pmod{\pi^3}$ to $f$.

Comment: In your case, $f$ is Eisenstein so unless $p^n=3$, $f$ mod $\pi^3$ is just $X^n$. The paper is behind a paywall so it’s hard to see the context of its author’s statement. I’d be surprised if none of the references of  the paper (maybe Serre’s *Local fields*) mentioned estimates resembling this one. The link with upper-numbering ramification and Hasse-Arf (in the abelian case at least) might be worth checking out.

Comment: The paper cites Krasner and Serre as references. Also, the results seem to only apply to cyclic extensions (at least for odd $p$), by the discussion at the beginning of Section 3 and Theorem 2.2.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to me like the discussion in Section 3 uses cyclicity to deduce distinctness of the ramification numbers, but doesn't that follow from the fact that the residue field of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$, using my argument in the question?

Comment: Yes, but not only – cyclicity means that you can use Hasse-Arf which gives you strong constraints on the $v_i$. IIRC Serre’s book investigates this situation quite carefully.